# Android - Java - Regular Expression question - consecutive words not being matched

Tags: java, android, regex

For my example I am trying to replace ALL cases of "the" and "a" in a string with a space.
Including cases where these words are next to characters such as quotes and other punctuation

```
String oldString = "A test of the exp."
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(((\\W|\\A)the(\\W|\\Z))|((\\W|\\A)a(\\W|\\Z)))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(oldString);
newString = m.replaceAll(" ");
```

"A test of the exp." returns "test of exp." - Yeah!

"A test of the a exp." returns "test of a exp." - Boooo!

"The a in this test is a the." returns "a in this test is the. - DoubleBoooo!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: No need to put "Android - Java - Regular Expression" as part of the question, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\b(?:a|the)\\b", " ");
```

`\b` matches at a word boundary (i. e. at the start or end of a word, where "word" is a sequence of alphanumeric characters).

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, needed to separate the alternative words (in this case `a` and `the`) from the surrounding word boundary anchors.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the extra info on the (?:...) non-capturing group. After reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html I now know that this makes my expression slightly more efficient.  I also am still using the Pattern+Matcher since I will be using this expression several times and documentation says it is more efficient than String functions, especially if the same pattern is to be used more than once. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Or per simplified @Robokop soln.

```
Pattern.compile("(\\b(the|a)\\b)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

or

```
Pattern.compile('\b(the|a)\b',Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Not sure about quoting in Java.

Comment: The first version is correct.  Java string literals are always double-quoted, and you always have to escape backslashes if you want them to appear in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern.compile("(\\bthe\\b)|(\\ba\\b)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```